# Проверка цифровой подписи

Tags: windows, безопасность

интересует следующий вопрос: проверяет ли ОС Windows, свои системные библиотеки, файлы, приложения (имеющие ЭЦП microsoft), на подлинность при помощи хэш-суммы? Если да, то в какой момент и каким образом, может есть для этого какие-либо технологии и т.д.?

Comment: Драйвера без подлинной подписи в принципе не загрузятся. А всё остальное вроде бы не проверяется (даже ядро почему-то) и выявится только командой sfc /scannow (из личного опыта, могу ошибаться)

Comment: @andreymal а проверяются ли библиотеки при загрузке в системные процессы